# Drawing blur circle with canvas

Tags: android, canvas, blurry

I want to make blur effect at the start of needle

[image]

For this i use `BlurMaskFilter`, but the blurry circle drawn on needle is almost invisible.

To draw the needle i use:

```
    handPath = new Path();
    handPath.moveTo(0.5f, 0.5f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f - 0.010f, 0.5f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f - 0.010f, 0.5f - 0.32f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f + 0.010f, 0.5f - 0.32f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f + 0.010f, 0.5f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f, 0.5f);
    // Add blur effect
    handBlurPaint = new Paint();
    handBlurPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    handBlurPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(8, Blur.NORMAL));
```

To draw the hand i use

```
        float handAngle = degreeToAngle(handPosition);
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.rotate(handAngle, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        canvas.drawPath(handPath, handPaint);
        canvas.restore();
        //Add blur effect           
        canvas.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.1f, handBlurPaint);
```

And the result

[image]

I tried

```
.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(8, Blur.NORMAL))
```

and

```
.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL))
```

What should i do to achieve the effect?
Thank you in advance.

**Update**

Here in this [2D graphics with Effects](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/07/2d-graphics-with-effects_11.html) link, Blur filter is working.

**Update2**

Using `RadialGradient` i managed to do almost the same what i want. Thanks to @dwana

```
handBlurPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.2f,Color.BLACK, Color.TRANSPARENT, TileMode.MIRROR));
```

and the result

[image]

Comment: You could use gradient to get a similar result, although not perfect

Comment: @dwana i tried it with `RadialGradient` and updated the question with example. You can copy paste it and i will accept

Comment: also this `handPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.3f, Color.BLACK, Color.parseColor("#E51400"), TileMode.CLAMP));` directly apply on the needle, no need to draw other circle